# Is there any number limitations of field for Redis command HMSET?

Tags: redis

What's the max number limitation of field for Redis command HMSET ? If I set 100000 fields to one key by HMSET , if would cause the performance issue comparing to use the each field as a key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is quite large, 2^64-1 in 64 bit systems, and 2^32 -1 in 32 bit systems, 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/redis-db/eArHCH9kHKA/UFFRkp0iQ4UJ

> 1) Number of keys in every Redis database: 2^64-1 in 64 bit systems.
>   2^32-1 in 32 bit systems. 2) Number of hash fields in every hash:
>   2^64-1 in 64 bit systems. 2^32-1 in 32 bit systems.
>
> Given that a 32 bit instance has at max 4GB of addressable space, the
>   limit is unreachable. For 64 bit instances, given how big is 2^64-1,
>   the limit is unreachable.
>
> So for every practical point of view consider keys and hashes only
>   limited by the amount of RAM you have.
>
> Salvatore

Answer (score 10):

I did a couple of quick tests for this using the lua client.

I tried storing 100,000 fields using a single hmset command, individual hmset commands, and pipelined individual commands, and timed how long they took to complete:

hmset   100000   fields:    3.164817

hmset individual fields:    9.564578

hmset in pipeline:  4.784714

I didn't try larger values as 1,000,000+ were taking too long but the code is here if you'd like to tinker. https://gist.github.com/kraftman/1f15dc75649f07ee044eccab5379a8e3

Depending on the application bear in mind that you loose the storage efficiency of hashes once you add too many fields('too many' can be set, see [here](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your test ,however my scenario is one key and 10000 fields.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong terminology: I set one key 'newhash', with 100,000 fields, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), there's no such limitation.

> actually the number of fields you can put inside a hash has no practical limits (other than available memory)

I think there's no performance penalty to save data in a `HASH`. However, if you have a very large `HASH`, it's always a bad idea to call `HGETALL`. Because `HGETALL` returns all fields and values of the `HASH`, and that would block the Redis instance for a long time when the `HASH` is very large.

Whether a `HASH` is better than key-value store, largely depends on your scenario.

Comment: so the performance for 100000 key and value pairs is almost the same as to one key and 100000  fields with hash?

Comment: @Jason Yes, the performance is almost the same. Theoretically speaking, `HASH` might be slower, since Redis needs search the key index first, then search the `HASH`'s field index (2 index searches VS 1 index search). However, the index searching is very very fast, and you can ignore the difference. I once did some similar test, and the performance is almost the same.